# How to write Serilog output to console in Visual Studio Unit Tests?

Tags: serilog

I am trying to write unit tests with output to log - Serilog. 
But when I am debugging them in Visual Studio (Test Explorer) I can't see the Serilog output in console.

Any ideas?

```cs
public abstract class AbstractTest
{  

  static AbstractTest()
  {
    var loggers = new LoggerConfiguration()
      .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
      .Enrich.FromLogContext();

    loggers.WriteTo.Logger(logger => logger
      .WriteTo.Console(restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Verbose));

    Log.Logger = loggers.CreateLogger();
    Log.Logger.Information("Logger is initialized");
  }

}

[TestClass]
public class DemoTest : AbstractTest
{
  private static ILogger log = Log.ForContext(typeof(DemoTest));

  [TestMethod]
  public void DemoTst()
  {
    log.Debug("test");
  }

}
```

Neither 'Logger is initialized' nor 'test' is displayed in console.

I am using 'Serilog.AspNetCore' and 'Serilog.Sinks.Console'

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Ok I found a solution.

You have to include package `Serilog.Sinks.Debug` ([here](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-debug)) into your project and initialize it with `WriteTo.Debug()`.

Comment: This worked for me, but I didn't have to add the Debug package, just added the "Debug" to the "WriteTo" section in my appsettings (.net core)

Comment: @pabrams you have to be more specific. Read first https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Configuration-Basics and https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Getting-Started

Comment: For reference, when adding debug to the serilog json config file, it's just a name/value setting: `"WriteTo": [ { "Name": "Debug" }, { "Name: "Console", "Args": ... } ]`. In other words, only the name of the sink needs to be added to the array; no need for any args/configuration.